# TSQL to get DISTINCT records ordered and then apply row numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I asked a question regarding processing lockouts in a software activation scenario where older activations are locked out when newer activations are processed.

[SQL Server Stored Procedure to dump oldest X records when new records added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097604/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-dump-oldest-x-records-when-new-records-added)

I ran into a problem and hopefully someone can help.  Let's assume the Activations table has the following columns:

CustomerName, ProductName, KeyCode, ActivationDate

I need to get unique CustomerName, ProductName, and KeyCode data as you could activate the same machine multiple times.  The result set needs to be ordered by ActivationDate DESC so I can work with the data in the order activated.  So in my scenario I may allow the last two activations to work, all prior to get logged into a Lockouts table so they are locked out with the new activations being recorded.

How can I get a unique/distinct resultset ordered and THEN apply row numbers so I can iterate the resultset and discard the latest activations and work with the older activations to lock them out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do what you want:

```
select t.CustomerName, t.ProductName, t.KeyCode, t.MaxDate,
       row_number() over (order by t.MaxDate desc) as RowNum
    from (select CustomerName, ProductName, KeyCode, max(ActivationDate) as MaxDate
              from Activations
              group by CustomerName, ProductName, KeyCode) t
```

It could also be written using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), which would look like:

```
;with cteMaxDate as (
    select CustomerName, ProductName, KeyCode, max(ActivationDate) as MaxDate
        from Activations
        group by CustomerName, ProductName, KeyCode
)
select t.CustomerName, t.ProductName, t.KeyCode, t.MaxDate,
       row_number() over (order by t.MaxDate desc) as RowNum
    from cteMaxDate t
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: 
You want all the rows with row number that are not the max ActivationDate

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    CustomerName    VARCHAR(20),
    ProductName     VARCHAR(20),
    KeyCode         INT,
    ActivationDate  DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'cmp1', 'game', 28734, GETDATE() -1    UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp1', 'game', 28734, GETDATE() -1.5  UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp1', 'game', 28734, GETDATE() -1.2  UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp1', 'game', 28734, GETDATE() -1.8  UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp1', 'game', 28734, GETDATE()       UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp1', 'game', 28734, GETDATE() -17   UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp2', 'game', 28736, GETDATE() -1    UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp2', 'game', 28736, GETDATE() -1.5  UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp2', 'game', 28736, GETDATE() -1.2  UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp2', 'game', 28736, GETDATE() -1.8  UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp2', 'game', 28736, GETDATE()       UNION ALL
SELECT 'cmp2', 'game', 28736, GETDATE() -17     


SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActivationDate DESC) RowNumber,
              CustomerName, 
              ProductName, 
              KeyCode, 
              ActivationDate        
FROM @tbl workTable
WHERE ActivationDate != 
    (
        SELECT MAX(ActivationDate)
        FROM @tbl checkTable
        WHERE workTable.CustomerName = checkTable.CustomerName
            AND workTable.ProductName = checkTable.ProductName
            AND workTable.KeyCode = checkTable.KeyCode
    )
```

---

```
RowNumber     CustomerName     ProductName     KeyCode  ActivationDate
1             cmp1             game            28734    2011-02-24 08:40:45.790
2             cmp2             game            28736    2011-02-24 08:40:45.790
3             cmp2             game            28736    2011-02-24 03:52:45.793
4             cmp1             game            28734    2011-02-24 03:52:45.793
5             cmp1             game            28734    2011-02-23 20:40:45.790
6             cmp2             game            28736    2011-02-23 20:40:45.790
7             cmp2             game            28736    2011-02-23 13:28:45.790
8             cmp1             game            28734    2011-02-23 13:28:45.790
9             cmp1             game            28734    2011-02-08 08:40:45.790
10            cmp2             game            28736    2011-02-08 08:40:45.790
```

---

If you want more than one...

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActivationDate DESC) RowNumber,
        CustomerName, 
        ProductName, 
        KeyCode, 
        ActivationDate      
FROM @tbl workTable
WHERE NOT ActivationDate IN 
    (
        SELECT TOP 2 ActivationDate
        FROM @tbl checkTable
        WHERE workTable.CustomerName = checkTable.CustomerName
            AND workTable.ProductName = checkTable.ProductName
            AND workTable.KeyCode = checkTable.KeyCode
        ORDER BY ActivationDate DESC
    )
```

Comment: It won't touch these two: cmp2, game, 28736, '2/25/11 8:50' and cmp1, game, 28734, '2/25/11 8:50'